# Excel VBA - for each label / user form

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel `Userform` and on it I have several `Labels`, some of which are on a `Frame`.

Is the following possible?

```
For each label [that is on the frame]
    [code]
Next label
```

If yes, how do you do that?
Or can you group some of them and then control them as members of that group like

```
For each label in [groupname]
    [code]
Next label
```

?
If yes, how do you do that? I tried to group them, but no success.

I would like that userform to serve as a `user input interface` with a dashboard-kind of thing on it too... Of course that would be much easier to do on a `worksheet`, but then you couldn't really make it look nice and `userform`-like, could you? (I.e. run as a small window without the menu or anything other than the area of what would be the "userform".)

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is possible thanks to the collections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for looping all labels within form:

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
        Debug.Print ctrl.Name
    End If
Next ctrl
```

And this for looping labels within a frame (name `Frame1` in my case)

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Frame1.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
        Debug.Print ctrl.Name
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Comment: @metrazol [Control type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224135(v=office.11).aspx) documentation has good information on this as well

Answer (score 0):

To expand it a bit. Works also for MS Access as following to map the used labels.

Form OnOpen event :

```
 Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
 List_Labels Me.Form
 End Sub
```

Called Subroutine (i keep them in a separate module):

```
Sub List_Labels(ByRef frm As Form)
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
        Debug.Print frm.Name & " - " & ctrl.Name & " value: " & ctrl.Caption
    End If
Next ctrl
End Sub
```